# How to run 2 different processes at once in Python

Tags: windows-7, python-3.x

I'm trying to code a program in Python 3 running Windows 7. I want the program to be able to display text in a window and play an audio file at the same time. I can successfully complete both processes at different times. How do I complete these processes at the same time? Here is a code block taken from the program:

```
     import lipgui, winsound, threading
     menu = lipgui.enterbox("Enter a string:") 
     if menu == "what's up, lip?":
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2), args=(None))
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=lipgui.msgbox("The sky is up"), args = (None))
```

Comment: Can you please show more code ahead from where you have given. What happens in your current code? It should work and make both run at the same time.

Comment: Edited it. This is the full script. It still does them at separate times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` argument of `Thread` must point to a function to execute.  Your code evaluates the function before passing it to `target`.

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2), args=(None))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=lipgui.msgbox("The sky is up."), args = (None))
```

is functionally the same as:

```
val1 = winsound.PlaySound("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=val1, args=(None))
val2 = lipgui.msgbox("The sky is up.")
t2 = threading.Thread(target=val2, args=(None))
```

What you actually want to do is pass only the function to `target` ***before*** it's evaluated and pass the arguments you want to pass to the desired function in the `args` parameter when instantiating `Thread`.

```
t1 = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound, args=("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2))
t2 = threading.Thread(target=lipgui.msgbox, args=("The sky is up.",))
```

Now t1 and t2 contain Thread instances with references to the functions you want to run in parallel along with the arguments.  They still aren't running the code yet.  To do that you need to run:

```
t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Make sure you don't call `t1.run()` or `t2.run()`.  `run()` is a method of Thread that `start()` normally runs in a new thread.

The final code should be:

```
import lipgui
import winsound 
import threading

menu = lipgui.enterbox("Enter a string:") 
if menu == "what's up, lip?":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound, args=("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=lipgui.msgbox, args=("The sky is up",))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Now when I run this, it plays the audio, and the program continues to run but it doesn't display the GUI!

Comment: Hello? I still cant figure this out!

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: I think the problem is that we are doing t1.start and t2.start on separate lines.

Comment: I really need help with this!

Comment: Your code looks the same as I remember it.  With my suggestions it should look like this:
`
import lipgui
import winsound 
import threading

menu = lipgui.enterbox("Enter a string:") 
if menu == "what's up, lip?":
   t1 = threading.Thread(target=winsound.PlaySound, args=("C:/Interactive Program/LIP Source Files/skyisup.wav", 2))
   t2 = threading.Thread(target=lipgui.msgbox, args=("The sky is up"))

   t1.start()
   t2.start()
`

Comment: I'll post it in the answer.

Comment: Oh... Now I run it and I get this error: TypeError: msgbox() takes from 0 to 5 positional arguments but 14 were given

Comment: I edited it.  If you have a tuple with 1 element, you have put a comma at the end, otherwise the interpreter doesn't parse it as a tuple. 
('The sky is up',)

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to do this for a LONG time!